# Is there any where I can just make a post for math stack exchange that's not a question?

Tags: discussion

Just wanted to thank you guys properly. I made it through one of my toughest classes yet, and couldn't have done it without the community on here!

Comment: That is nice to hear! You can do the same for others by helping on their question. Surely there are more students who have though classes :).

Comment: I think there is no right place to thank here. But if you feel is worth it, you can thank the community in the Acknowledges of your thesis! :) And maybe there is a _particular_ user that helped you in a extraordinary way;  you could mention this user in your thesis and of course let him/her know about it.

Comment: It's nice to see something nice for a change.

Comment: You may put a note of thanks in your profile.

Comment: Nice! Good luck in whatever is next for you.

Comment: Maybe you can use [chats](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I think you just accomplished your mission. Congratulations!

Comment: maybe make this a forum for thanks :)

Comment: @YuiToCheng it's not a duplicate since the former is a particular case of the later. Here OP is asking for a place _to make a post_ to thank whereas on the other question is asking in general 'best way to thank'